# jQuery Promise doesn't trigger .then() or .done()

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, jquery-deferred, deferred

I'm trying to use a promise to make sure a certain function doesn't fire until another function has returned. I've looked at a lot of examples, others' problems etc., and as far as I can tell my syntax is correct, but my `.then(function())` won't run, so I must be missing something.

```
function previewMaster () {

var dfd = $.Deferred(); 

  function prevAndTest() {
    return true;
  }

  var doneYet = false;

  var intvl = setInterval(function() {
    if (doneYet === false) {
      doneYet = prevAndTest();
      //reassign doneYet until true
    } else {
      clearInterval(intvl);
      dfd.resolve;
     return dfd.promise();
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

neither `.then()` nor `.done()` work here:

```
var promise = previewMaster();
  promise.then(function() {
    alert("finished");
  });
```

Comment: `dfd.resolve;` is a function ... use `dfd.resolve("value to resolve the promise to because that's what promises do");`

Comment: also, where you are returning `dfd.promise()` is completely wrong - you need to return it from the previewMaster function, not the callback to the setInterval

Comment: @JaromandaX is absolutely correct. Docs: https://api.jquery.com/deferred.resolve/

Comment: can't return inside `setInterval` . Nothing is returned at all from `previewMaster `

Comment: you can return inside `setInterval` - the returned value just isn't going anywhere :p

Comment: So, the code should look like https://jsfiddle.net/jaromanda/6LgsjLLv/

Comment: awesome. thanks so much guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You solution does not work because the method `previewMaster` is not returning the promise:

```
function previewMaster () {
    ...
    return dfd.promise();
}
```

and because you need to call the `resolve` function when you want to resolve the promise:

```
dfd.resolve();
```

See the complete example here:

```
function previewMaster () {

    var dfd = $.Deferred(); 

    function prevAndTest() {
        return true;
    }

    var doneYet = false;

    var intvl = setInterval(function() {
        if (doneYet === false) {
        doneYet = prevAndTest();
        //reassign doneYet until true
        } else {
        clearInterval(intvl);
        dfd.resolve(); // <- resolve method must be called to resolve the promise.
        // return dfd.promise(); // <- Do not return the promise here
        }
    }, 1000);
    return dfd.promise(); // <- Return the promise here
}
```